# How do I write a DataTable to a SQL Server table using SqlBulkCopy, where the target table has an identity column?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that writes a DataTable to a SQL Server table. This script is part of a larger project that already performs this numerous times, however in this instance, the first column of the target table is an IDENTITY column that needs to be preserved. When I try to write to the table I think the columns are all misaligned because I am getting the error:

```
Exception calling "WriteToServer" with "1" argument(s): "The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type decimal of the specified target column."
```

Any way I can let SqlBulkCopy know in advance that there is a column to be ignored?

Comment: Maybe you defined the first column in the datatable with the wrong type? Show us your code :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The datatable doesn't contain the ID column. It was my hope that the SqlBulkCopy would start writing from the 2nd column, given the first is an identity.

Comment: Not by default, but you can override that behavior by adding mappings for the remaining columns to `SqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I don't suppose you know where I can find more information on this? I can only find things in a c# context, not Powershell.

Comment: It's the same, same underlying type system (.NET) :)